# How to display data in a table from an array inside an object inside an array in Vue.js?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have an array called cars which has 2 objects. In that object I have another array called brands. Inside that i have another array called models.

I want to display the data in the models array in a table using Vue.js This is what I'm getting so far.

[image]

I'm new to Vue.js and programming, so please help me with this problem. TIA

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Vehicle Search Form</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-check form-group">
                <label for="car">Choose a Car Type</label>
                <select v-model="selectedCar">
                    <option v-for="car in cars" :value="car" :key="car.carId">{{car.car}}</option>
                </select>
                <label for="brand" v-if="selectedCar != -1">Choose a Brand</label>
                <select v-model="selectedBrand" v-if="selectedCar != -1">
                    <option v-for="brand in selectedCar.brands" :key="brand.id">{{brand.brand}}</option>
                </select>

                <table style="width:100%" v-if="selectedCar != -1 && selectedBrand != -1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Models</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="model in selectedCar.brands.models" :key="model">
                        <td></td>
                        <td> {{model}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {},
        data() {
            return {
                cars: [
                    {
                        carId: 1,
                        car: 'SUV',
                        brands: [
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                brand: 'Ford',
                                models: ['Ford EcoSport', 'Ford Expedition', 'Ford Edge', 'Ford Escape']
                            },
                            {id: 2, brand: 'GMC', models: ['GMC Terrain', 'GMC Suburban']},
                            {id: 3, brand: 'Dodge', models: ['Journey', 'Grand Caravan']},
                            {id: 4, brand: 'Mercedes-Benz', models: ['G-Class']},
                            {id: 5, brand: 'Audi', models: ['Audi Q3', 'Audi Q5', 'Audi Q5', 'Audi Q7']}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        carId: 2,
                        car: 'Sedan',
                        brands: [
                            {brand: 'Dodge', models: ['Charger', 'Challenger', 'Durango']},
                            {brand: 'Mercedes-Benz', models: ['C-Class', 'AMG', 'E-Class', 'S-Class']},
                            {brand: 'Audi', models: ['Audi A4', 'Audi A8', 'Audi RS 3']}
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                selectedCar: -1,
                selectedBrand: -1,
                // selectedModel: -1
            }
        },
    };

</script>

<style scoped>
    select {
        border: 1px solid rgb(27, 189, 154);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your did confuse property names. I renamed your variables and fixed the issue.
You forgot to bind the values of each brand to the select option `:value="brand"`.

```js
<select v-model="selectedBrand" v-if="selectedCar != -1">
  <option v-for="brand in selectedCar.brands" :key="brand.id" :value="brand">{{brand.brand}}</option>
</select>
```

Here's working updated code:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#container",
         data() {
            return {
                cars: [
                    {
                        carId: 1,
                        car: 'SUV',
                        brands: [
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                brand: 'Ford',
                                models: ['Ford EcoSport', 'Ford Expedition', 'Ford Edge', 'Ford Escape']
                            },
                            {id: 2, brand: 'GMC', models: ['GMC Terrain', 'GMC Suburban']},
                            {id: 3, brand: 'Dodge', models: ['Journey', 'Grand Caravan']},
                            {id: 4, brand: 'Mercedes-Benz', models: ['G-Class']},
                            {id: 5, brand: 'Audi', models: ['Audi Q3', 'Audi Q5', 'Audi Q5', 'Audi Q7']}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        carId: 2,
                        car: 'Sedan',
                        brands: [
                            {brand: 'Dodge', models: ['Charger', 'Challenger', 'Durango']},
                            {brand: 'Mercedes-Benz', models: ['C-Class', 'AMG', 'E-Class', 'S-Class']},
                            {brand: 'Audi', models: ['Audi A4', 'Audi A8', 'Audi RS 3']}
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                selectedDesign: null,
                selectedBrand: null,
            }
        },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
    <div>
        <h1>Vehicle Search Form</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-check form-group">
                <label for="car">Choose a Car Type</label>
                <select v-model="selectedDesign">
                    <option v-for="car in cars" :value="car" :key="car.carId">{{car.car}}</option>
                </select>
                <label for="brand" v-if="selectedDesign">Choose a Brand</label>
                <select v-model="selectedBrand" v-if="selectedDesign">
                    <option v-for="brand in selectedDesign.brands" :key="brand.id" :value="brand">{{brand.brand}}</option>
                </select>
                <table style="width:100%" v-if="selectedBrand">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Models</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr v-for="model in selectedBrand.models" :key="model">
                        <td></td>
                        <td> {{model}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

You can always initialize the data using `null` and when you use `v-if` conditional rendering the `null` is considered as false.
Check JavaScript **Truthy** and **Falsy** on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: Thank u. Will try this.

Comment: @ND You're welcome. If this answer solves your problem, please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you need to get selected brand models and display them in next select.
So  you can do it using computed property and :value attribute for option:

```html
    <select v-model="selectedBrand" v-if="selectedCar != -1">
        <option
            v-for="(brand, index) in selectedCar.brands"
            :key="brand.id"
            :value="brand.id"
        >
            {{brand.brand}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

This template will insert an id of selected brand to selectedBrand property, then you can create computed property which will represent selected brand object:

```js
    computed: {
        selectedBrandObject() {
            let selectedBrand = {};
            for(let brand of this.selectedCar.brands) {
                if(parseInt(brand.id, 10) === parseInt(this.selectedBrand, 10)) {
                    selectedBrand = brand;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return selectedBrand;
        }
    }
```

Than you can have access to selected brand in the template, so:

```html
    <tr v-for="model in selectedBrandObject.models" :key="model">
        <td></td>
        <td> {{model}}</td>
    </tr>
```

So there will be only selected brand models. If you need more info about computed properties, you can look [here](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: Thank u. Will try this.